# How to make a variable loaded from .dir-locals.el global?

Tags: elisp

I save the variable in `.dir-locals.el` like this:

```
  (add-dir-local-variable 'nil 'CurrentProjectStat CurrentProjectStat)
  (save-buffer)
  (kill-buffer)
```

When I upload a file with a given project, this variable is loaded only for this buffer, but I need it to be loaded globally. I use this variable in the form of widgets, this is a different buffer, and this variable is no longer there.

I do not know in which direction to look, overriding the variable does not help.

Tell me please how to make such a variable global?

Comment: I came up with a solution, it is ugly, but it works. Create a file containing a command to assign a global variable a value, and when loading a project file, execute the contents of the file by hook. like this:    ```(let (( varsfile (concat (projectile-project-root) "/.globalvars.el")))
      (when (file-exists-p varsfile)
        (load-file varsfile )))```

Comment: If you want a variable to be global, don't use directory-local variables at all.  However you think that is going to work is inevitably going to be flawed.  You will get a better result if you elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve overall, as there is probably a better solution.

Comment: @phils . I am trying to create, for my needs, a project generator. as a meson assembly system, an irony auto-completion system. It seemed to me good ideas to store project state variables, such as: project type, assembly directory, assembly type, etc. - in the file .dir-locals.el. But for convenience, I made a menu and widget's forms, it is dynamic and uses part of the variables as keys to dynamically display items, and then there were problems with the visibility of variables when the project loads, after rebooting emacs. In the end, I came to the same decision that you proposed.

Comment: If you use global vars and you have *more than one* of these projects open, then you will surely get cross-contamination of the values.  Presumably what you need is buffer-local values within your widgets buffer.  Without knowing more about how you're creating that buffer (or how it is accessing values), it's difficult to know what to recommend; but presumably you would be passing enough state to the new buffer that it would have (or be able to fetch) the data it needed.  Calling `hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer` in your new buffer might be another solution.

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t even think about data pollution when opening files of different projects. So far, ideas on how to solve this are to register an update of the global variable through  `focus-on-hook`. I will show the repository with the project, just uploaded the data. I ask for leniency. This is my first such big project on elisp, in fact, I study elisp on it. The project has grown, but it is in one file and there are probably many more problems. Therefore, please be lenient. https://github.com/Silerus9768/MiniIDE

Comment: Ok, so that's ~2000 lines of elisp with dependencies I don't use, so I'm not going to review that for the purposes of this question.  I suggest that you add to the question a *minimal* test-case demonstrating the behaviour.

Comment: I propose that the problem be resolved, albeit with reservations. Your advice helped me a lot, including thinking about the consequences. I will optimize the project after bringing it up to work on all the points I have outlined. Your first comment, I would note as the right answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of answering the question as stated:

You can use the pseudo-variable `eval` to evaluate arbitrary code, and therefore set a non-local variable (assuming the variable is not already buffer-local), like so:

```
((nil . ((eval . (setq GLOBALVAR VALUE)))))
```

I strongly doubt that this is actually what you want to do, however.